# Understanding `GHC.TypeLits`

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to wrap my head around the GHC extensions `KindSignatures` and `DataKinds`. Looking at the [Data.Modular](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Modular.html) package, I understand roughly that

```
newtype i `Mod` (n :: Nat) = Mod i deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

is sort of equivalent to declaring a c++ template `<typename T, int N>` (with the constructor taking only one argument of type `T`). However, looking at the [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) package, I don't understand most of what is happening. Any general explanation about this package would be helpful. Before this question gets flagged as off topic though, here are some specific sub-questions:

- a `KnownNat` class makes sense, with required function letting you extract the type variable from the type, but what does `natVal` do, and what is the `proxy` type variable?
- Where would you use `someNatVal`?
- Finally, what is `SomeNat` - how can a type level number be unknown? Isn't the whole point of a type level number that it **is** known at compile time?

Comment: No, types do not all have to be known at compile time. For instance, when compiling `id` it is not known what all possible arguments will be.

Comment: @augustss Good point, but then what is the purpose of `SomeNat`?

Comment: It's a type for an existentially quantified type.  You know it's of kind Nat, but not exactly which type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is quite broad -- I'll address a few points, only.

The `proxy` type variable is just a type variable of kind `* -> *`, i.e. the kind of type contructors. Pragmatically, if you have a function

```
foo :: proxy a -> ...
```

you can pass to it values of type e.g. `Maybe Int`, choosing `proxy = Maybe` and `a = Int`. You can pass also values of type `[] Char` (also written as `[Char]`). Or, more commonly, a value of type `Proxy Int`, where `Proxy` is a data type defined as

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

i.e. a data type which does not carry any run-time information (there's a single value for it!), but which carries compile-time information (the *phantom* type variable `a`).

Assume `N` is a type of kind `Nat` -- a compile-time natural. We can write a function

```
bar :: N -> ...
```

but calling this would require us to build a value of type `N` -- which is immaterial. The purpose of type `N` is to carry compile-time information, only, and its run-time values are not things that we really want to use. In fact, `N` could have no values at all, except for bottom. We *could* call

```
bar (undefined :: N)
```

but this looks weird. Reading this, we must realize that `bar` is lazy in its first argument and that it will not cause divergence trying to use it. The problem is that the `bar :: N -> ...` type signature is misleading: it claims that the result may depend on the value of the argument of type `N`, when this is not really the case. Instead, if we use

```
baz :: Proxy N -> ...
```

the intent is clear -- there's only a single run-time value for that: `Proxy :: Proxy N`. It is equally clear that the `N` value is only present at compile time.

Sometimes, instead of using the specific `Proxy N`, the code is slightly generalized to

```
foo :: proxy N -> ...
```

which achieves the same goal, but permits also different `Proxy` types. (Personally, I'm not terribly thrilled by this generalization.)

Back to the question: `natVal` is a function which turns a compile-time only natural into a run-time value. I.e. it converts `Proxy N` into `Int`, returning just the constant.

You analogy with C++ templates might get closer if you used *type* template arguments to model compile time naturals. E.g.

```cpp
template <typename N> struct S { using pred = N; };
struct Z {};

template <typename N> int natVal();
template <typename N> int natVal() { return 1 + natVal<typename N::pred>(); }
template <>           int natVal<Z>() { return 0; }

int main() {
    cout << natVal<S<S<Z>>>() << endl;  // outputs 2
    return 0;
}
```

Just pretend there are no public constructors for `S` and `Z`: their run-time values are unimportant, only their compile-time information matters.

Comment: An important reason for the use of proxies is that the type-level `a` you're trying to pass in might not have kind `*`.  For instance, `proxy 3 -> b` is well-kinded, but `3 -> b` is not; `proxy Maybe -> b` is well-kinded, but `Maybe -> b` is not.

Comment: Furthermore, `undefined :: N` is only well-kinded if N has kind *.